# How to optimize a recursive function

Tags: python

I currently have a function that is supposed to update every dictionary key where the value is the old _id to be the value of a new uuid.

This function works as intended but isn't efficient and takes too long to execute with my current dataset.

What has to happen:

1. Each `dict['_id']['$oid']` has to be changed to a new uuid.
2. Every `$oid` that matches the old value must be changed to new uuid.

*The problem is that there are many `$oid` keys in every dictionary and I want to make sure this works correctly while being more efficient*

As of right now the script takes 45-55 seconds to execute with my current dataset and it's making 45 million calls to the recursive function `recursive_id_replace`

How can I optimize the current function to get this script to run faster?

The data gets passed into this functions as a dictionary that looks like:

```
file_data = {
    'some_file_name.json': [{...}],
    # ...
}
```

Here's an example of one of the dictionaries in the dataset:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "4e0286ed2f1d40f78a037c41"
    },
    "code": "HOME",
    "name": "Home Address",
    "description": "Home Address",
    "entity_id": {
      "$oid": "58f4eb19736c128b640d5844"
    },
    "is_master": true,
    "is_active": true,
    "company_id": {
      "$oid": "591082232801952100d9f0c7"
    },
    "created_at": {
      "$date": "2017-05-08T14:35:19.958Z"
    },
    "created_by": {
      "$oid": "590b7fd32801952100d9f051"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "$date": "2017-05-08T14:35:19.958Z"
    },
    "updated_by": {
      "$oid": "590b7fd32801952100d9f051"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "01c593700e704f29be1e3e23"
    },
    "code": "MAIL",
    "name": "Mailing Address",
    "description": "Mailing Address",
    "entity_id": {
      "$oid": "58f4eb1b736c128b640d5845"
    },
    "is_master": true,
    "is_active": true,
    "company_id": {
      "$oid": "591082232801952100d9f0c7"
    },
    "created_at": {
      "$date": "2017-05-08T14:35:19.980Z"
    },
    "created_by": {
      "$oid": "590b7fd32801952100d9f051"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "$date": "2017-05-08T14:35:19.980Z"
    },
    "updated_by": {
      "$oid": "590b7fd32801952100d9f051"
    }
  }
]
```

Heres the function:

```
def id_replace(_ids: set, uuids: list, file_data: dict) -> dict:
    """ Replaces all old _id's with new uuid. 
        checks all data keys for old referenced _id and updates it to new uuid value.
    """

    def recursive_id_replace(prev_val, new_val, data: Any):
        """
        Replaces _ids recursively.
        """
        data_type = type(data)

        if data_type == list:
            for item in data:
                recursive_id_replace(prev_val, new_val, item)

        if data_type == dict:
            for key, val in data.items():

                val_type = type(val)

                if key == '$oid' and val == prev_val:
                    data[key] = new_val

                elif val_type == dict:
                    recursive_id_replace(prev_val, new_val, val)

                elif val_type == list:
                    for item in val:
                        recursive_id_replace(prev_val, new_val, item)

    for i, _id in enumerate(_ids):
        recursive_id_replace(_id, uuids[i], file_data)

    return file_data
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253984/how-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-keyword-in-arbitrarily-structured-data/45254036#45254036

Comment: Suggest you first profile your code to determine where to try optimizing it. See [**_How can you profile a script?_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script)

Comment: @martineau I've profilied this script already, that's how I know the function is being called 45 million.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't know if it's the best way. Although it's a different way of solving this problem and i'm going to attempt to tweak the code to deal with this problem as strings just like in your answer in the link.

Comment: It's possible the overhead of recursion is the issue, but that's not all the function does. There's also a module called the [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/2.0) that will give you more insight into the inner workings function's code, which I also suggest using, it's fairly easy to use. Also, by inspection I think I see something _very_ inefficient (as well as being a potential bug) going on, but need to run the code to make sure. Could you add a simple testcase that has a minimal number of `_ids` and `uuids` that correspond to the what in the sample json data?

Comment: Another question: Why are you passing the `file_data` argument supplied to `id_replace()` on to `recursive_id_replace()`? The function doesn't do anything with it except pass it to itself (recursively)?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried the way you showed in that ticket by marshalling data into a str and using .replace and I gained a 50X speed up in execution. I was getting between 45-55 seconds and now the script executes in 1 second. If you want to create an answer, I'll make sure to select it and upvote it as well.

Comment: Alright done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one technique that involves stringifying your data with `json` and *then* doing the replacement.

```
In [415]: old_uid = "590b7fd32801952100d9f051"

In [416]: new_uid = "test123"

In [417]: json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace('"$oid": "%s"' %old_uid, '"$oid": "%s"' %new_uid))
Out[417]: 
[{'_id': {'$oid': '4e0286ed2f1d40f78a037c41'},
  'code': 'HOME',
  'company_id': {'$oid': '591082232801952100d9f0c7'},
  'created_at': {'$date': '2017-05-08T14:35:19.958Z'},
  'created_by': {'$oid': 'test123'},
  'description': 'Home Address',
  'entity_id': {'$oid': '58f4eb19736c128b640d5844'},
  'is_active': True,
  'is_master': True,
  'name': 'Home Address',
  'updated_at': {'$date': '2017-05-08T14:35:19.958Z'},
  'updated_by': {'$oid': 'test123'}},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '01c593700e704f29be1e3e23'},
  'code': 'MAIL',
  'company_id': {'$oid': '591082232801952100d9f0c7'},
  'created_at': {'$date': '2017-05-08T14:35:19.980Z'},
  'created_by': {'$oid': 'test123'},
  'description': 'Mailing Address',
  'entity_id': {'$oid': '58f4eb1b736c128b640d5845'},
  'is_active': True,
  'is_master': True,
  'name': 'Mailing Address',
  'updated_at': {'$date': '2017-05-08T14:35:19.980Z'},
  'updated_by': {'$oid': 'test123'}}]
```

Just remember, only works with lists and dictionaries. Other data structures will either be implicitly converted or an error thrown.

More methods outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253984/how-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-keyword-in-arbitrarily-structured-data/45254036#45254036).